# Javascript - innerHTML in for loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, innerhtml

I have problem with getting innerHTML value from element in "for" loop. This is my code:

```
for (i; i<count; i++) {
document.getElementsByClassName("element")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    quantity = document.getElementsByClassName("quantity")[i].innerHTML;
    console.log(quantity);
});r
}
```

Loop is working correctly but I can't get innerHTML value from clicked object.

**EDIT:**
I have tried to do something like this:

```
for (i; i<count; i++) {
 document.getElementsByClassName("dodaj_do_koszyka")[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // dodaj(i);
    console.log(i);
});
}
function dodaj(i) {
 var quantity = document.getElementsByClassName("quantity")[i].innerHTML;
 console.log(quantity);
}
```

Still doesn't work. **i** from for loop shows me numbers(iterations?) of **i**, not the value.

Comment: What is your html structure like?

Comment: My HTML is:
`<tbody>
    <tr><td class="quantity">50</td><td class="netto">50 zł</td><td class="brutto">61,50 zł</td><td><a href="#" class="element">Dodaj</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="quantity">100</td><td class="netto">100 zł</td><td class="brutto">123 zł</td><td><a href="#" class="element">Dodaj</a></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="quantity">200</td><td class="netto">200 zł</td><td class="brutto">246 zł</td><td><a href="#" class="element">Dodaj</a></td></tr>
</tbody>`